# Replace a link with it's text with jQuery

Tags: jquery

```
<a href="#">TEST</a>
```

I want to remove the anchors and keep the Text i.e TEST

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You could also use the new [`$.unwrap`](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/) method (*jQuery 1.4+*) applied to the [`contents`](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) of the anchor:

```
​$('a').contents().unwrap();​​
```

Check an example [here](http://jsbin.com/agobo).

Comment: +1 I initially tried this, but I must have not loaded 1.4 into jsbin, or I wrote "content" instead. Either way, good work.

Comment: It was so funny running that line of code on the console while on this page here on SO. All the upvote and comment links changed to being plain text items.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to remove the link and leave the text:

```
$("a").replaceWith(function(){ return $(this).text() });​
```

Online Demo: http://jsbin.com/aguki/edit

If you're using jQuery 1.4+, [CMS provided an even shorter answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2294071/replace-a-link-with-its-text-with-jquery/2294119#2294119).

Comment: @Jonathan, what made you change this from your first example?

Comment: Brevity. Using `.replaceWith()` was shorter.